# Request body for Table/Range related method are missing in the documentation of microsoft graph excel api

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api

I created a table using:

```
/v1.0/drives/{driveid}/items/{id}/workbook/worksheets/Sheet1/tables/add
```

with the request body:

```js
{ "address": "A1:C2"}
```

Unable to set data onto the table using:

```
/v1.0/drives/{driveid}/items/{id}/workbook/worksheets/Sheet1/tables/Table2/Range
```

with the request body:

```js
{ "values": [["a", "b", "c"], ["1", "2", "3"]] }
```

Getting this error:

```js
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidArgument",
    "message": "The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "ea584370-dbb3-486f-9190-0cb8586c911c",
      "date": "2017-08-21T12:44:48"
    }
  }
}
```

Can anybody suggest how to set data onto table with first row indicating header row in the request body?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for [adding a row to a table](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/tablerowcollection_add) is: `POST /workbook/tables/{id|name}/rows/add`.

The following example is from the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/tablerowcollection_add):

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive/items/{id}/workbook/tables/{id|name}/rows/add
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 51

{
  "index": null,
  "values": [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6]
  ]
}
```